# Why when i'm setting big size when cloning new objects some of them are out of the terrain area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CloneObjects : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject objectToClone;
    public int objectsStartingHeight = 20;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] objects;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _objectCount;
    private float _objectSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int ObjectCount;
    public float ObjectSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Clone();
        objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("objectToClone");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        ObjectCount = Mathf.Max(0, ObjectCount);
        ObjectSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, ObjectSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        ObjectCount = 100;
        ObjectSize = 20.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void Clone()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && ObjectCount == _objectCount && Mathf.Approximately(ObjectSize, _objectSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var ObjectToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");
        foreach (var t in ObjectToDestroy)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < ObjectCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(objectToClone);
            o.tag = "ClonedObject";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, ObjectSize, ObjectSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            //o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y+objectsStartingHeight, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _objectCount = ObjectCount;
        _objectSize = ObjectSize;
    }
}
```

If i set to clone 10 objects and the size is 20 it's fine.
But if i change the size to 50 and there is a new object spawn near the terrain edge the object will be half on the terrain half out of the terrain area.

The terrain position is X = -250 Y = 0 Z = -250
The terrain size is Width = 500 Length = 500 Height = 600

How can i fix it ?

In the screenshot the marked/clicked object is half in the terrain half out.

[image: Big size objects]

This is a screenshot of the object the script is attached to and the settings on the inspector:

[image: Script settings]

Update

What i tried is to change this 3 lines:

```
var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
var y = Extents.y;
var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);
```

To

```
var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x + (float)(0.5 * o.transform.localScale.x), Extents.x - (float)(0.5 * o.transform.localScale.x));
var y = (float)0.5 * Extents.y;
var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z + (float)(0.5 * o.transform.localScale.z), Extents.z - (float)(0.5 * o.transform.localScale.z));
```

But then i'm getting in some places two cubes each inside the other one. 
Also there is no space between the cubes and i need to have spaces and maybe even to add some variable to be able to control the space between the cubes the position is random but to decide some minimum space limit.

[image: Cubes inside each other]

Answer (score 0):

Raycasts are very thin and are cast from the middle of each cube. If you want your cubes to fit inside the terrain, you need to reduce your extents by the half the width of the cube. Let me know if it works.

You don't divide by 2. Maybe I misinterpreted your code. The part where you get random position. You need to change this:
`var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);`
to something that looks like this:
`var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x + (0.5*currentCubeWidth) , Extents.x - (0.5*currentCubeWidth);`

The above is pseudocode, I am not sure where you are defining the cube size in your game. They all appear to be different sizes. This should also be done for x, y and z.

Comment: Where do i reduce the extents by half ? In the bottom of the code ? Or inside the Reset() ? And how ? Should i reduce by half each value x,y,z by 2 ? /2 ?

Comment: I should have been clear. You don't divide by 2. Maybe I misinterpreted your code. The part where you get random position. You need to change this:
`var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);`
to something that looks like this:
`var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x + (0.5*currentCubeWidth) , Extents.x - (0.5*currentCubeWidth);`

The above is pseudocode, I am not sure where you are defining the cube size in your game. They all appear to be different sizes. This should also be done for x, y and z.

Comment: The cube size i define in the editor in the inspector in the script: Object Size in the code i'm using the Object Size in this line: o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, ObjectSize, ObjectSize); and all the cubes are in the same size.

Comment: I just updated my question with what i did and what i'm getting. I guess i did it wrong.